# Invalid or unexpected token a variable in java-script

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, append

I am appending a select box on button click the select box value are fetched from the query but one  file does not take the name that shows the error in console  Invalid or unexpected token a variable
the appending code is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#btnAdd").click(function() { 
$(".zims").append('<tr> <td><select name="material_id[]" required class="s_box"><option value="">-Select Material-</option><?php foreach ($get_mat as $row) {  ?><option value="<?php echo $row->id ?>"><?php echo $row->name ?></option> <?php } ?>  </select> </td></tr>');
}); });
```

**$row->name** is problem! the when replacing the name with the id that's working

the query is

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('material');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

why that show this how to solve this issue anyway?
the name is in that loop the plus button not working but that replace to id that working!!

**$get_mat** result is

```
array(33) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#97 (2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> string(5) " Nail" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#98 (2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["name"]=> string(6) "Washer" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#99 (2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "3" ["name"]=> string(5) "L bow" } [3]=> object(stdClass)#100 (2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "4" ["name"]=> string(9) "Chemical " } [4]=> object(stdClass)#101 (2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "5" ["name"]=> string(19) "Polishing material " } [5]=> object(stdClass)#102 (2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "6" ["name"]=> string(6) "Paints" } [6]=> object(stdClass)#103 (2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "7" ["name"]=> string(3) "Bit" } [7]=> object(stdClass)#104 (2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "8" ["name"]=> string(6) "Cement" } [8]=> object(stdClass)#105 (2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "9" ["name"]=> string(7) "M Sand " } [9]=> object(stdClass)#106 (2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "10" ["name"]=> string(7) "P Sand " } [10]=> object(stdClass)#107 (2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "11" ["name"]=> string(11) "20 mm metal" } [11]=> object(stdClass)#108 (2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "12" ["name"]=> string(5) "Chips" } [12]=> object(stdClass)#109 (2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "13" ["name"]=> string(7) "Q dust " } [13]=> object(stdClass)#110 (2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "14" ["name"]=> string(13) "Baniyan waste" } [14]=> object(stdClass)#111 (2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "15" ["name"]=> string(13) "Cutting blade" } [15]=> object(stdClass)#112 (2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "16" ["name"]=> string(15) "Electrical item" } [16]=> object(stdClass)#113 (2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "17" ["name"]=> string(14) "Plumbing item " } [17]=> object(stdClass)#114 (2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "18" ["name"]=> string(15) "Carpentry item " } [18]=> object(stdClass)#115 (2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "19" ["name"]=> string(14) "Painting item " } [19]=> object(stdClass)#116 (2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "20" ["name"]=> string(4) "Rope" } [20]=> object(stdClass)#117 (2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "22" ["name"]=> string(11) "Level hose " } [21]=> object(stdClass)#118 (2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "23" ["name"]=> string(7) "Fissure" } [22]=> object(stdClass)#119 (2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "24" ["name"]=> string(11) "40 mm metal" } [23]=> object(stdClass)#120 (2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "25" ["name"]=> string(13) "Hardware Item" } [24]=> object(stdClass)#121 (2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "26" ["name"]=> string(6) "Bricks" } [25]=> object(stdClass)#122 (2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "27" ["name"]=> string(6) "Rubble" } [26]=> object(stdClass)#123 (2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "28" ["name"]=> string(6) "Steel " } [27]=> object(stdClass)#124 (2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "29" ["name"]=> string(14) "Polishing item" } [28]=> object(stdClass)#125 (2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "30" ["name"]=> string(11) "silicon gun" } [29]=> object(stdClass)#126 (2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "31" ["name"]=> string(13) "Granite Blade" } [30]=> object(stdClass)#127 (2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "32" ["name"]=> string(5) "Blade" } [31]=> object(stdClass)#128 (2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "33" ["name"]=> string(5) "Water" } [32]=> object(stdClass)#129 (2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "34" ["name"]=> string(11) "Glass Point" } }
```

Comment: Do you know PHP does not work in the Javascript?

Comment: @DanishAli its working the name is probelum

Comment: I don't think so. Anyway you need to render `<select>` in the controller and then append in the view.

Comment: @ag $row->name contains any special char? can you show us your $get_mat  data array?

Comment: @DanishAli its writing in view page button click append to the next line

Comment: @M.Hemant no var dump the variable $get_mat show all data

Comment: @M.Hemant watch my question ,updated

Comment: try <?php echo trim($row->name); ?>

Comment: @M.Hemant its working thank you brother

Answer (score 0):

please change appending code like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#btnAdd").click(function() { 
$(".zims").append('<tr> <td><select name="material_id[]" required class="s_box"><option value="">-Select Material-</option><?php foreach ($get_mat as $row) {  ?><option value="<?php echo $row->id ?>"><?php echo trim($row->name) ?></option> <?php } ?>  </select> </td></tr>');
}); });
```

this name has some whitespace remove the space using trim